# Why this script for changing the player position is not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity its my 4day working on it . I was following a 2D platformer tutorial I followed every step but when the player enter the portal collider it don't  teleport the player to another position  like in the video it don't do anything.

Here is the code

```
class playerDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]private Transform portalNextPosition;
    private Vector3 offset;
    private void Start()
    {
        offset = new Vector2(1, 0);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.tag == "player")
        {
            collision.transform.position = portalNextPosition.position + offset;

            

        }
    }




}
```

I tried debug a message when the player collide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i read this script is attached to your portal and you are trying to detect when the player colliders with your portal
using if this gameobject tag equals to a string

one of these issues may be happening

- Case sensitive

c# is a case sensitive language so if your player tag is Player and you typed player instead it won't detect your Player so try and change your code to this

```
public class playerDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]private Transform portalNextPosition;
    private Vector3 offset;
    private void Start()
    {
        offset = new Vector2(1, 0);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            collision.transform.position = portalNextPosition.position + offset;
        }
    }
 }
```

- set your portal colliders  to triggers

in your code you are using OnTriggerEnter2D which as it says 2D colliders and triggers so if your object collider isn't in 2D or isn't set to trigger it won't work
go to your portal collider and check istrigger box and make sure you are using 2D colliders

- didn't even assign tag to your Player

Check if your player gameobject has the Player Tag so it can be detected game objects in defualt are untagged you have to assign tags manually

Comment: Thanks it worked but why are we checking if tag equals something can i use gameobjects instead